# avoid multiple vector drawable object

Tags: android, drawable, android-vectordrawable

In my application, each time I inflate a recycler view list item I need to set its drawable color,

```
Drawable drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.outgoing_message_background)).mutate();

DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable, mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.lighterColorAccent));
```

how can I effectively store that drawable to avoid coloring it multiple times
I can't add multiple versions to a drawable folder because the drawable colors are set at runtime and I thought about static variables to hold the drawable but then I realized that's a memory leak

thanks in advance

Comment: The drawable color is fixed in your codes: getColor(R.color.lighterColorAccent), so what is the mean about " set at runtime "

Comment: Actually you can change drawable colors at runtime 
with this code 

DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable, mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.lighterColorAccent));